# Trying to understand an example script on ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, prediction

I'm trying to work through an example script on machine learning: [Common pitfalls in interpretation of coefficients of linear models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_linear_model_coefficient_interpretation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-linear-model-coefficient-interpretation-py) but I'm having trouble understanding some of the steps. The beginning of the script looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

survey = fetch_openml(data_id=534, as_frame=True)

# We identify features `X` and targets `y`: the column WAGE is our
# target variable (i.e., the variable which we want to predict).
X = survey.data[survey.feature_names]
X.describe(include="all")

X.head()

# Our target for prediction is the wage.
y = survey.target.values.ravel()
survey.target.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

train_dataset = X_train.copy()
train_dataset.insert(0, "WAGE", y_train)
_ = sns.pairplot(train_dataset, kind='reg', diag_kind='kde')
```

My problem is in the lines

```
y = survey.target.values.ravel()
survey.target.head()
```

If we examine `survey.target.head()` immediately after these lines, the output is

```
Out[36]: 
0    5.10
1    4.95
2    6.67
3    4.00
4    7.50
Name: WAGE, dtype: float64
```

How does the model know that `WAGE` is the target variable? Does is not have to be explicitly declared?

Comment: Look at the structure of survey. It iss either a Pandas dataframe or an object with the data as the attributes.

Comment: Yes, and it is actually explicitly declared with `y = survey.target.values.ravel()`. The variable _y_ is commonly used as a symbol for the targets.

Comment: Yes, I understand the variable `y`, but where in there does it specify `WAGES` as the target variable? I think I'm misunderstanding the `survey.target.values.ravel()` bit. When I use the method on my own data, how do I specify what variable is the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `survey.target.values.ravel()` is meant to flatten the array, but in this example it is not necessary. survey.target is a pd Series (i.e 1 column data frame) and survey.target.values is a numpy array. You can use both for train/test split since there is only 1 column in `survey.target` .

```
type(survey.target)
pandas.core.series.Series

type(survey.target.values)
numpy.ndarray
```

If we use just survey.target, you can see that the regression will work:

```
y = survey.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

train_dataset = X_train.copy()
train_dataset.insert(0, "WAGE", y_train)
sns.pairplot(train_dataset, kind='reg', diag_kind='kde')
```

[image]

If you have another dataset, for example iris, I want to regress petal width against the rest. You would call the column of the data.frame using the square brackets `[]` :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

dat = load_iris(as_frame=True).frame

X = dat[['sepal length (cm)','sepal width (cm)','petal length (cm)']]
y = dat[['petal width (cm)']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

LR = LinearRegression()
LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
plt.scatter(x=y_test,y=LR.predict(X_test))
```

[image]